# Append Class to List<Class> With Condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Person
{
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public Info Info {get;set;}
}

public class Info 
{
  public string Key {get;set;}
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I have a `List<Person>` with values in `Key` field but `Info` field is **null**

I have a `List<Info>` with values in all fields.

I want to assign each `Info` for its `Person` Depending on the `Key` value

How can I do this with linQ?

Comment: `foreach` loop?

Comment: "public Info Info {get;set;}" does it compile?

Comment: Post your code till you have tried.

Comment: @t.m. Sure, why not? A member can have the same name as its type.

Comment: @t.m. You can have a property name with the same name as its type name if that’s what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you want to assign the persons to the infos when all the persosns further properties except the key itself don´t contain any data?

Comment: Yes, that was what I am asking thanks.

Comment: List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
            List<Info> info = new List<Info>();

            (from p in people
             join i in info on p.Key equals i.Key
             select new { person = p, info = i })
             .Select(x => x.person.Info = x.info);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `foreach` should do

```
foreach (var person in people)
{
    person.Info = infos.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == person.key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your info list to a lookup based on the keys first, and then loop through the persons, retrieve the info item and assign it.

```
var infoLookup = infoList.ToDictionary(i => i.Key);

foreach (Person p in personList)
{
    Info info;
    if (infoLookup.TryGetValue(p.Key, out info))
        p.Info = info;
}
```

We could also use `infoList.FirstOrDefault()` instead of converting it into a dictionary first but that way, we would add a linear search for *every* person. By converting it into a dictionary first, we have a one-time linear cost for the conversion and then can look up the info object with constant time. So the total time complexity is only linear (since we still need to loop through all persons).

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var person in myPersonList)
{
    item.Info = myInfoPerson.Where(o => o.key == person.key).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: you can replace `Where` directly with the `FirstOrDefault` ;)

Comment: Please, add some information to the answer, explaining what it does or how it works.

Answer (score -2):

This will works.

`info.ForEach(x => {
             person.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == x.Key).Info = x;
        });`